# alternating control flow with conditionals or preprocessor

Tags: python

Given this code:

```
for i in range(5):
  foo(i)
  bar(i)
```

I want to add some code between the two `print` lines such that I can break the loop into two, but only if a certain flag is true, i.e.:

```
for i in range(5):
  foo(i)

if debug: {
  continue
for i in range(5):
}

  bar(i)
```

Unfortunately this is not valid python. Is there a way I can do that without manually rewriting the loop to:

```
if debug:
  for i in range(5):
    foo(i)
  for i in range(5):
    bar(i)
else:
  for i in range(5):
    foo(i)
    bar(i)
```

Comment: No, there is no preprocessor in Python, so you cannot use any equivalent of preprocessor-style directives. Can you share more details or more concrete example? Right now it smells of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - tell us _what_ you want to do, not _how_ you want to do it.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thanks. The above is exactly what I am trying to do. I am looking for a way to break the loop w/o changing the arguments to `foo` and `bar` or changing the bodies of those functions.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this a little more, maybe adding a little more context and what the functions are doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am looking for a generic solution that will work for any functions.

Comment: Maybe a decorator might work or manipulating the source at runtime with ast but without seeing the bigger picture it is hard to really come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to either call functions in batches (all possible args for first function, then all possible args for second function etc) in first case, and arguments in batches in second case (so all function for first arg, then all functions for second arg etc.)

I'd say you have to do it explicitly:

```
def foo(i):
    print("foo", i)

def bar(i):
    print("bar", i)

def stretch(seq, n):
    """stretch([1,2,3], 3) -> [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], lazy generator"""
    for o in seq:
        for _ in range(n):
            yield o


def run(args, functions, mode):
    if mode:
        my_args = list(stretch(args, len(functions)))
        my_functions = functions * len(args)
    else:
        my_args = args * len(functions)
        my_functions = list(stretch(functions, len(args)))
    for f, a in zip(my_functions, my_args):
        f(a)
```

Invocation:

```
run(list(range(5)), [foo, bar], 0)
```

Output:

```
foo 0
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
bar 0
bar 1
bar 2
bar 3
bar 4
```

Invocation:

```
run(list(range(5)), [foo, bar], 1)
```

Output:

```
foo 0
bar 0
foo 1
bar 1
foo 2
bar 2
foo 3
bar 3
foo 4
bar 4
```

Here what we've done is that we created pairs for `(callable, argument_to_callable)` if order determined by your requirement. So essentially you have a boolean that "kind of" duplicated a loop for you.

Code is kind of ugly, I wonder if someone comes up with nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm we can always store mid-air result in list

```
n = range(10) 
if debug:
    n = list(map(lambda x: foo(x),n))+list(map(lambda x: bar(x),n))
else:
    n = list(map(lambda x: [foo(x),bar(x)],n))
```

Answer (score -1):

Preprocessor derivatives change your code before it ever gets to run. In the C family of languages, for example, the compiler substitutes all expressions within [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) blocks before compilation.

In your example, `debug` is a runtime variable, so there is no way you could change the structure of your code based on that variable. At least not in Python anyway.

However, there is **always** (well, almost always) a way you can avoid doing something manually. 
In the same spirit of true preprocessor blocks changing the code before it gets to run, we have to go a level up and add in content before the code gets executed.
The simplest way to do that is to manipulate your code as a string, and modify the string on the run.
I won't stress enough how unpythonic this contrived example is, but using `exec` you can inject the code you want. The solution will always work, no matter what function you use. Here it goes:

First, define your debug flag

```
if_debug = ""
if debug:
    if_debug = "continue\nfor i in range(5):\n    "
```

Finally, wrap your code within a `exec("")` block. The string substitution happens before the code is sent to the interpreter for evaluation.

```
exec("""
for i in range(5):\n
    foo(i)\n    """
+ if_debug + 
   "bar(i)")
```

There are macro libraries that allow you to change the way your code gets interpreted. Have a look at [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), for example.

Comment: I don't see why this is getting downvoted. It answers the question asked by the OP.